# Check if element exists in map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, key

Is there any function to find if an element exists in a map (not a key).
For instance I have a map and want to find if a word is the second element of any pair from the map, and if so, what is its key.

Comment: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) But remember that you have to think of cases where the value could be multiple times in the map.

Comment: Looks like you chose a wrong data structure for your problem. Look at [Boost bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) or [Boost muli-index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Maps are organized by key, so short of iterating over each element there is no way to do this.

Assuming you are searching for `look_for`, you can use the standard library's `std::find_if`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(),
                       map.end(),
                       [&look_for](const auto& kv_pair) {
                            return kv_pair.second == look_for;
                       });
if (it != map.end()) {
    auto key = it->first;
    // ...
} else {
    // Value not found
    // ...
}
```

It is also possible to use a manual loop (`std::find_if` is often considered nicer, but here that might be overkill)

```
for (const auto& kv_pair : map)
    if (kv_pair.second == look_for)
        return kv_pair.first;
// If you reach this, the value isn't in your map
```

Comment: Might want to add a check for `map.end()` before dereferencing `it`.

Comment: Whoops, added that

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::find_if` with a lambda:

```
map<int,int> m;
m[1] = 10;
m[2] = 20;
m[3] = 30;
auto target = 20;
auto f20 = std::find_if(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [&](const auto& p) {
    return p.second == target;
});
if (f20 != std::end(m)) {
    // We have our value
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/zJGDtI)

Note that, unlike a search of keys that is logarithmic, search on values is linear.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning original key-value dictionary requires `O(n)` time and it might be slow.

To find specific value and its key fast, creating reverse dictionary is a way.
To original `std::map` for key-value, reverse dictionary is `std::unordered_multimap` for value-key.
The lookup time is `O(1)`.

Comment: Good recommendation. Just thought it should be mentioned that it requires you to be able to hash your value type.